# How to run scheduled scripts on linux without using cron?

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I am new to linux and shell scripting, can anyone help me create a .sh file to execute automatically every 5 hrs without using cron job

Comment: Why can't you use cron? Periodic execution is what it's designed for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right solution here is definitely cron, since it's specifically designed to handle periodic execution. If for some reason you need to avoid using it, here are some simple examples of scripts that repeatedly execute a fixed command.

Here's a naive solution that gets the job done.

```
#!/bin/sh

while true; do
    my_command
    # sleep 5 hours
    sleep $((5 * 60 * 60))
done
```

This will run the command every five hours if the time that the command runs is negligible, since the job is run synchronously. If the command takes one hour to run, then it will be every six hours.

If you need it to run every five hours exactly, you can do the following.
This command creates a lockfile in `/var/run` that exists when the job is running and is deleted when the job stops. This prevents multiple instances of the job from running at the same time. The main loop will wait for five hours for `my_command` to finish after it's been started, and will check every 60 seconds to see if the lockfile has been removed.

```
#!/bin/sh

lockfile=/var/run/my_command.lock
[ -f "$lockfile" ] && {printf 'lockfile already exists\n'; exit 1;}
while true; do
    if [ ! -f "$lockfile" ]; then
        touch "$lockfile"
        (my_command ; rm "$lockfile") &
        sleep $((5 * 60 * 60))
    else
        printf '%s\n' "skipping! process is already running"
        sleep 60
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `at` command inside your script to reschedule it again after certian time.
You could put something like this at the end of your `.sh` script
`at now +5 hours ~/myscript.sh`

So every time your script finish execution it will be rescheduled to execution after 5 hours. This approach has its downsides and using cron would be the ideal way.

Comment: If the objective is to run every 5 hours regardless of how long the script takes, the `at` command should be at the top, not the bottom.  However, using `at` is a cheat of sorts; jobs scheduled by `at` are run by `cron`.

Comment: Running `at` at start or end depends on the requirement. I have used this approach once because I do not had the admin access to the linux box. I had permission to execute `at` but not `cron`.

Comment: I came here searching for a command for scheduled one-time command execution. So this answer helped me ;-)